# Struggling with aliases in case statements and math operations

Tags: sqlite, yelp

I am working with the [Yelp database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOhAs.png) and would like to run a query using only the user table:

- Calculate the number of years a user has been on Yelp. Those that have been on the platform for 1 year will be group "young", those with at least 5 years in the platform will be group "old";
- For these groups, I also want to calculate the average number of reviews written per year (review_count divided by the number of years on Yelp).
- For the "old" group, I want to divide the number of fans by the review_count (and find a ratio of fans per review).
- For the "young" group, I want to multiply their current average number of reviews per year x 5, and then multiply this number by the ratio of fans per review of the "old" group.

I am a beginner (as you can obviously tell) and have tried everything I know, but I cannot find a way to make this work. I have created date and math operations which I then tried to use in case statements, but that doesn't work.

Any helpful tips please?

Thanks!

By the way, this is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS number_of_users
,SUM(review_count) / SUM(fans) AS reviews_fan_ratio
,(DATE('now') - yelping_since) AS years_on_yelp
,SUM(review_count) / years_on_yelp AS reviews_per_year
  ,CASE
    WHEN years_on_yelp <= 5 THEN 'young'
    WHEN years_on_yelp > 5 THEN 'old'
    END age
FROM user
GROUP BY age;
```

Comment: Please, show us what you have done so far (the SQL).

Comment: Hi Olivier, thanks for the reply. I've just added a piece of code.

Comment: How that "doesn't work"? Which errors are there?

Comment: I've amended the code to represent as much as what I wanted to achieve with the query. The error I get is "no such column: years_on_yelp", which is what I would like to use in my case statement. After solving this, I would still need to run a couple more math operations, but those would involve the results of other calculations as opposed to columns originally present in the table.

Comment: You know, it's very difficult to read the code from the small picture and constantly switch between it and your post. Can you please add your table structure as a text, i.e. the output of the command `.schema` or `.schema user` in sqlite3 program?